# Auto-saving files upon changes with Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have used [WebStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#WebStorm) from JetBrains for almost four years now. It's a fantastic IDE for many reasons, but one of the best features is that it saves versions of files outside of version control. So if you accidentally delete files or lose files before they are saved by your version control system, WebStorm has a copy of them and there are visual diff tools to use. This feature has saved me on more than one occasion.

For Visual Studio Code, is there some feature/plugin that will auto-save copies of files as they change? Will Visual Studio Code save the files to some central location, or perhaps in the `.vscode` folder in the local workspace?

The feature in WebStorm is available from *Local History* → *Show History* from a folder or file. Here is an article about it:
*[Using Local History for code changes tracking](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2012/10/using-local-history-for-code-changes-tracking/)*

The view looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 320):

You can go to menu *File* and choose *Auto Save*.

[image]

Comment: All this does is save the _current_ file though - it doesn't give you a backup copy?

Comment: @MikeBrockington You should use git for such matter

Comment: @Daneal How does GIT help me with my local workflow - I need local copies.

Comment: @MikeBrockington create a local git repo, then. You'll be able to jump to any commit and there's no need to have a remote origin

Comment: @Daneal Still doesn't give me local COPIES of each FILE, and what it does give is at the expense of a massive change to workflow for me and my colleagues, and requires a new tool that we don't currently use.

Comment: This may not have answered the OP's question, but it answered mine. After getting used to IntelliJ automatically saving after each change, when I switched to VSCode I keep finding it a pain to make sure I have saved every file I changed before compiling.

Comment: Local history is super useful feature, autosave is not a replacement. Question should've been titled as 'local history in VSC' not 'auto save in VSC'

Comment: Just wanted to add that the proper way to use git is to have a local git repo in your project, so when you commit git changes, they are only saved locally in the local git repo under the .git directory in your project. Then when you want to send those changes to others, you push them to the github repo.

Also, the latest version of VSCode has local history feature, just like Jet Brains tools.

Answer (score 122):

You can enable auto save with one of this methods:

**Method 1**. Check the **Auto Save** item in the *File* menu

[image: Visual Studio Code auto save activation]

**Method 2**. Go to *Settings*, search for **auto save**, and select the auto save option (afterDelay)

[image: Visual Studio Code auto save activation]

[Auto save description in Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_save-auto-save)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think the second step is necessary anymore. After doing the first step, the setting was already as you described in your second step and I didn't need to change anything. Maybe VSCode developers ready your post and set "Auto Save" to "afterDelay" by default for the newer versions :) Please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 41):

Yes, Visual Studio Code can auto-save changes on files as you make changes. It also allows you set a delay for how long to wait before saving the file.

Here's [a link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_save-auto-save) that should help you with that.

Or a shortcut you can simply navigate to your Visual Studio Code settings, and add the following to your `settings.json` file.

```
{
    ...
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 1000,
    ...
}
```

This will instruct your editor to autosave after a 1000 ms delay. You can set the autosave option to `onFocusChange` to autosave whenever you move your cursor away from the current text area.

Comment: yes, but does it store a copy of the file contents to a location other than the file path?

Comment: @AlexanderMills No

Comment: It could be an advantage to have both: delay **AND** onFocusChange.

Comment: Is there a `default` time for autosave?

Answer (score 17):

There's a package called [Local History](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyz.local-history) that can be used to save a backup of your files outside version control.

You should check that out.

Comment: Very cool, but it does come with issues.  For one, make sure to add the `.history` folder to your `.gitignore` file (_because that .history folder is created within your main working folder_).

Comment: When does it store exactly? After closing VScode? After saving? After a n sec timestamp?

Answer (score 6):

As of March 2022 (version 1.66), Visual Studio Code has a built-in feature called [Local History](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_66#_local-history) that automatically creates commit-like versions of your files on every save.

It is enabled by default, but you can double check the setting *workbench.localHistory.enabled* to make sure it is enabled in your project.

From the reference:

> Each local history entry contains the full contents of the file at the time the entry was created and in certain cases, can provide more semantic information (for example, indicate a refactoring).
>
> From an entry you can:
>
> - Compare the changes to the local file or previous entry.
> - Restore the contents.
> - Delete or rename the entry.

The saved local versions are accessible from the **Timeline** section in the *File Explorer* tab.

Answer (score 1):

Also, ensure you add *.history* to your *.gitignore* file, so Visual Studio Code doesn't track every change made to a single file as changes made to multiple files. This can be a problem and make your files changed so large even though it's a single file or a few files you made edits to.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.