# Auto format as you type

Tags: visual-studio-code, format

I have configured VS Code and ESLint to automatically lint and format
my code.
The problem is that currently VS Code auto formats only if I press
<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (Save).
I was wondering if there is a way to auto format as I type or after a
couple of seconds after typing? VS Code automatically saves the file
but that doesn't trigger the auto format.
I have to specifically press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to trigger
the auto format.

Answer (score 2):

Before I move on, I want to question whether using ESLint to format
code is a good idea?

Why do I ask? – Because ESLint is a linter and not a formatter.
A good alternative would be to use for example [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)
instead.

#### 1. Existing options

The existing options are explained at [the official VS Code
documentation on formatting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_formatting).

There are three options :

- `editor.formatOnType` - format the line after typing,
- `editor.formatOnSave` - format a file on save, and
- `editor.formatOnPaste` - format the pasted content.

Each of these three options has its limitation and does not offer the
functionality that I want.
(And it seems you want the same functionality as I do.)

In short, the only of the three options that formats the entire
file is `formatOnSave`.
But to format a file on save,
[*the file must not be saved after delay*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings).

#### 2. A desired new feature – **Format on Delay**

I would love the possibility to *format* with a time
delay, just as [it is possible to *save* with a time delay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59500985).

I *want* to have the freedom to both **Format on Delay** *and* to
[**Auto Save (on Delay)**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_save-auto-save).

This is not possible in the current release of VS Code (April 2022).

To make this [a Backlog milestone](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Issues-Triaging#up-voting-a-feature-request)
– we have until May 30 (2022) to get the needed 20 votes.
In case you want to vote on my suggestion,
[here is where you can vote by giving it a thumbs up](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146546).