# Github Visual Studio making me Save Changes before push?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I'm a novice and watching the freecodecamp Git tutorial. We are using Visual Studio Code. But in her videos if she makes a change to one of the files, Say "README.md", Visual Studio automatically recognizes that changes were made when she inputs >git status

For some reason I have to go to File -> Save in Visual Studio every time before it realizes changes were made and ready to be committed to Git? Over time this extra step can become a headache.

Does anyone know how I can get it to automatically recognize I am modifying the Git Repo file? Hope this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: She is using `Ctrl+S` (`Cmd+S` for Mac) to save files. It's much faster than going to File -> Save

Comment: Or she has autosaved enabled on VS Code: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53181761/2745495. Either way, you need to save the changes made to the file before Git can recognize it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto-saving files upon changes with VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53181761/auto-saving-files-upon-changes-with-vscode)