# Latex Workshop does not autobuild in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I'm trying to switch to Latex Workshop for VSCode, however I cannot get it to build after change.
I have it enabled in the settings, however it does not autobuild. After building manually the log says

```
Auto Build Run is temporarily disabled during a second.
```

at some point. I also made sure that Polling is active.

What is that supposed to mean and what is the fix?

I tried to set up Latex Workshop to autobuild, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug. The way that I got auto build working was to enable autosave, because the "build on change" setting does seem to work and so the auto save triggers an auto build. Some instructions to enable autosave can be found e.g. in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53181832) (in conjunction with the settings you mention).

Comment: Please see [answering questions with links to other answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113437/answering-questions-with-links-to-other-answers-on-stackoverflow)